# Why does having $X_0 = 1$ mean that the hyperplane includes the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, affine-geometry

I was just reading [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/185634/163242) question on stats.stackexchange, because I had the same question about why having $X_0 = 1$ means that the hyperplane includes the origin, and why it is an affine set cutting the $Y$-axis at the point $(0, \hat{\beta}_0$) if the constant is not included in $X$. However, I don't think the answer actually *explains* this; rather, it seems like it just restates it in a verbose way. And judging by the mathematics involved, I think that it would be a more appropriate question for the minds at math.stackexchange. So I am looking for a clear explanation of why this is the case; that is, why does having $X_0 = 1$ mean that the hyperplane includes the origin, and why it is an affine set cutting the $Y$-axis at the point $(0, \hat{\beta}_0$) if the constant is not included in $X$?

The textbook section is **2.3.1 Linear Models and Least Squares** from [here](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/). The relevant parts are all at the beginning of section 2.3.1.

---

### EDIT:

The part that I'm interested in is

> Often it is convenient to include the constant variable $1$ in $X$, ...

and

> In the $(p + 1)$-dimensional input-output space, $(x, \hat{Y})$ represents a hyperplane. If the constant is included in $X$, then the hyperplane includes the origin and is a subspace; if not, it is an affine set cutting the $Y$-axis at the point $(0, \hat{\beta}_0)$.

Comment: The only way that I can make sense of this is if $1$ is actually notation for the variable $X_0$, and not the actual value for the zeroth coordinate, so $1$ is a function $1\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $1(x)=x$ taking the value $0$ at $0$. That's at least what I can take away from the oxymoronic sentence "it is convenient to include the **constant variable** $1$". Then the notation $\hat Y=\beta_0+\sum \beta_j X_j$ simplifies to $\beta_0+\sum \beta_j X_j=\beta_0\cdot 1+\sum \beta_j X_j=\beta_0X_0+\sum \beta_j X_j=X^T\beta$.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Hmm, I see what you mean. It seems that this is even more confusing than I had originally thought. But you make a good argument.

Comment: I would say, ignore that post on stats.se - don't ask us to explain that answer because it is not well written, and does not make much sense mathematically. Instead, you should ask us the question you are really interested in having answered. (For example, that original question does not say that "$X_{0}=1$ means that the hyperplane includes the origin", so if this is what you are asking about, give us more context about where you are reading this particular statement)

Comment: @MorganRodgers That's precisely why I asked this question: The answers on stats.stackexchange didn't make sense, and I wanted an answer from the mathematicians, who I thought would likely have a better understanding.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I believe that the question is in the title

Comment: @MorganRodgers Oh, ok. Is my comment about section 2.3.1 of the textbook inadequate? The textbook is freely available in pdf form from the link. (It's at the beginning of section 2.3.1).

Comment: @MorganRodgers Presumably from the linked textbook, section 2.3.1 where this statement appears.

Comment: In 2.3.1, I don't see a reference to the variable $X_{0}$, or the claim that the equation $X_{0}=1$ defines a hyperplane. Can you point this out?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Ok, it seems that, in my confusion, I've mixed in some elements from the stack.exchange question. The part that I'm interested in is "Often it is convenient to include the constant variable $1$ in $X$, ..." and "In the $(p + 1)$-dimensional input-output space, $(x, \hat{Y})$ represents a hyperplane. If the constant is included in $X$, then the hyperplane includes the origin and is a subspace; if not, it is an affine set cutting the $Y$-axis at the point $(0, \hat{\beta}_0)$."

Comment: @MorganRodgers it's on page 12, first paragraph, line 5: "If the constant is included in X, then the hyperplane includes the origin and is a subspace". The variable $X_0$ is not mentioned, but it's clear from the context that the "constant variable $1$" is included in $X$ as $X^T=(1,X_1,\dots,X_p)$, i.e. $X_0=1$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, it is not the equation $X_0=1$ that defines the hyperplane including the origin, it's the pair $(X,\hat Y)$ with $X=(X_0,X_1\dots,X_p)$ where $X_0=1$. This is written in section 2.3.1. If you just read that section, what OP is asking will be clear. I am not posting an answer because I do not know the answer.

Comment: The equation $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\cdots+\beta_p x_p$ is the equation of a hyperplane in the $p+1$-dimensional space of values of $(x_1,\dots,x_p,y)$. It's not a subspace because of $\beta_0$ (if $\beta_0\ne0$). The equation $y=\beta_0 x_0+\beta_1x_1+\cdots+\beta_p x_p$ is the equation of a hyperplane in the $(p+2)$-dimensional space of values of $(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_p,y)$, granted $x_0$ can take on any value. But it's not true, $x_0$ must always equal $1$: one may change the form of the equation, but it must be equivalent, or it's another model. I don't see how the sentence can be made correct.

Comment: In the preceding comment, I removed all hats for simplification, but they are important: the correct equation without the hats is $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+\cdots+\beta_p x_{ip}+\epsilon_i$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Did you read the textbook itself? So are you saying that what the authors have written is just plainly incorrect?

Comment: I don't need to read the book to tell you there is a problem if at the beginning the equation is $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{1}+\cdots+\beta_p x_{p}$ and in the end the author writes that $y=x^T\beta$ for arbitrary $x$. $x$ is not arbitrary, the assumption from the very beginning is that $x_0=1$, otherwise you are considering something else. I know the book is well regarded in the field of machine learning, but here it's nonsense.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Ok, I just wanted to make sure that I was understanding you correctly. I just went over what is written in the textbook, and it does not say $\hat{Y} = X^T \hat{\beta}$ for *arbitrary* $X$, so I'm not sure if you would still consider this as incorrect: "Often it is convenient to include the constant variable $1$ in $X$, include $\hat{\beta}_0$ in the vector of coefficients $\hat{\beta}$, and then write the linear model in vector form as an inner product $$\hat{Y} = X^T \hat{\beta} \tag{2.2}$$ where $X^T$ denotes vector or matrix transpose ($X$ being a column vector)."

Comment: I quoted the book p.12. "At an arbitrary input $x_0$ the prediction is $\hat y(x_0)=x_0^T\hat\beta$." Note that if you are "training" (or whatever) with data for which $x_0\ne1$ (not the same $x_0$ as in the previous sentence), then it's equivalent to do a regression without the constant regressor, and it's absolutely not the same model. I am sorry to insist, but this is nonsense, as well as saying that you don't describe the same geometrical object just because you have hidden the coefficient in $X$: there is a condition to hide this coefficient, which means $X$ is not arbitrary any longer.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Oh, I see what you're referring to. I haven't even reached that part yet, since I'm still trying to understand the part before it. Is it possible that the author is referring to two different things here? For instance, at the beginning of the section, the author mentions that $X^T = (X_1, X_2, \dots, X_p)$, but for the later part that you're referring to, the author mentions the "arbitrary input $x_0$". So could it be that $X_0 = 1$ and arbitrary $x_0$ are different objects?

Comment: @ThePointer Sure, it's not the same thing at all. $X$ (which is a matrix) is the data used as input (which is used to compute $\hat\beta$ through the normal equations, and $x_0$ in $y(x_0)$ is an arbitrary input you feed to the model ($x_0$ would correspond to a row of $X$, not to a column, except that it's arbitrary). The problem is that the vector $x_0$ is not arbitrary because its first element should equal $1$. From the beginning, the coefficient of $\beta_0$ is $1$. You can call it $X_0$ (column vector of ones in matrix form), it's still a column vector of ones, *not* arbitrary.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut In the equations $\hat{y}_i = \hat{y}(x_i^T) = x_i^T \hat{\beta}$ and  $\hat{y}(x_0) = x_0^T \hat{\beta}$, $x_0^T$ is a row vector, right? So that means that $x_0$ itself must be a column vector – not a row vector. Page 10 says that $x_i$ is a $p$-vector. It then says that "Since all vectors are assumed to be column vectors, the $i$th row of $\mathbf{X}$ is $x_i^T$, the vector transpose of $x_i$."

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut But, if I'm not mistaken, this would *still* imply that the input $x_0$ cannot be arbitrary, since we must then have that $x_0 = 1$ for all $p$ entries, right?

Comment: $y(x_0)=x_0^T\hat\beta$ is supposed to be equivalent to the equation of the model (you multiply each $x$ variable with each $\beta$ coefficient and sum the products. So, that's right, $\hat\beta$ and $x_0$ are column vectors, however $x_0$ holds the same kind of data as a *row* of $X$. Often, in a stat textbook, $x_0$ would be a row (to match the rows in $X$), $\hat\beta$ a column, and you would write $x_0\hat\beta$. Just a matter of convention, but the math is the same. $x_0$ is certainly not a vector of ones, or more accurately, it does not *need* to, only its first element needs to be a 1

Comment: Suggested reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Pages 10-11 say this: "In general, vectors will not be bold, except when they have $N$ components; this convention distinguishes a $p$-vector of inputs $x_i$ for the $i$th observation from the $N$-vector $\mathrm{\mathbf{x}}_j$ consisting of all the observations on variable $X_j$. Since all vectors are assumed to be column vectors, the $i$th row of $\mathbf{X}$ is $x^T_i$ , the vector transpose of $x_i$."

Comment: I'm fine with that, the notation is self-consistent: the rows of $X$, when considered as vectors, are column vectors. Hence the $x_0$ above is indeed a *row* of $X$. And the only constraint on $x_0$ is that its first element is $1$. Yet there is still a problem regarding the hyperplane/subspace sentence. But it's a minor one, I think.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I've gone over this very carefully, and I do not see the problem. The textbook is very clear, and I do not know how to state it more simply: (1) All vectors are assumed to be column vectors, and (2) the $i$th row of $X$ is $x_i^T$ – the vector transpose of $x_i$. I do not see how one can interpret this to mean that "$x_0$ would correspond to a row of $X$, not to a column, ...." It even explicitly says that the the $x_i^T$ correspond to the rows of $X$.

Comment: Which means precisely that $x_i$ is a row of $X$, written as a column. But I agree and I already answered that it's not a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equation $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1+\cdots\beta_p x_p$, where the unknowns are $(x_1,\dots,x_p,y)$, describes an affine hyperplane $H$ of the affine space $\Bbb R^{p+1}$, that does not pass through the origin if $\beta_0\ne 0$.

The equation $y=\beta_0x_0+\beta_1 x_1+\cdots\beta_p x_p$, where the unknowns are now $(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_p,y)$, describes an affine hyperplane of the affine space $\Bbb R^{p+2}$ that *does* pass through the origin (hence it's a subspace of dimension $p+1$ of $\Bbb R^{p+2}$ considered as a vector space).

**However**, to describe the same model, you have the additional constraint $x_0=1$, and these two equations together describe an affine subset $S$ of $\Bbb R^{p+2}$ that has $p$ dimensions. It's simply an embedding in $\Bbb R^{p+2}$ of the hyperplane $H$ defined above. It's not a subspace of $\Bbb R^{p+2}$ because for all $x\in S$, $x_0=1$. And it's not an hyperplane either because it has dimension $p$, not $p+1$.

Therefore, I regard the sentence *"If the constant is included in $X$, then the hyperplane includes the origin and is a subspace; if not, it is an affine set cutting the $Y$-axis at the point $(0,\hat\beta_0)$"*. as **wrong**.

That being said, I think it's a minor error that does not impair the subsequent exposition of the linear model. I have another concern about the randomness in the model being completelly hidden, but it's the introduction of the chapter, and later on the epsilons are introduced as expected, to address inference.

Comment: "The equation $y=\beta_0x_0+\beta_1 x_1+\cdots\beta_p x_p$, where the unknowns are now $(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_p,y)$, describes an affine hyperplane of the affine space $\Bbb R^{p+2}$ that *does* pass through the origin (hence it's a subspace of dimension $p+1$ of $\Bbb R^{p+2}$ considered as a vector space)." How? How does $y=\beta_0x_0+\beta_1 x_1+\cdots\beta_p x_p$ pass through the origin, but $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1+\cdots\beta_p x_p$ (for $\beta \not= 0$) does not?

Comment: @ThePointer Let's check. Set $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n=y=0$ in the first: the equation reduces to $\beta_0=0$. When $\beta_0\ne0$, it doesn't work, so $(0,0\dots,0)\notin H$. Note there are $p+1$ variables here. In the second equation, there is one more variable, $x_0$. Set $x_0=x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n=y=0$, the equation reduces to $0=0$. Bingo. So $(0,0,\dots,0)$ is indeed a solution. But I explain below why this is cheating.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So it's cheating because we can't just set $x_0=x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n=y=0$, since we need to set that $x_0 = 1$?

Comment: @ThePointer Exactly.

Comment: And since we set $x_0 = 1$, the vector space does not contain the origin, and so does not qualify as a subspace?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Wow, now I understand what you mean. This seems like a pretty big mathematical error, since it seems like their entire strategy for justification was just plain wrong. Although, it was a **really** good catch on your part, because no one else has yet even mentioned this error! Pretty awesome. :)

Comment: @ThePointer It's not that bad. It's an error, but here he is just getting to the normal equations in order to find $\beta$. In the regression model, $X$ is observed data and $\beta$ is what we are looking for. And you can find the normal equations either in the simpler matrix form (with $X$) or with the original $\beta_0$ apart: they are the same, as the model is the same. Then inference can give you confidence intervals on the $\beta$ coefficients, etc. Really a minor problem.

Comment: Ok. And related to this is the other issue that they claimed that $x_0$ is arbitrary, right? If we say that $x_0 = 1$, then $x_0$ is actually a $p$-vector with $1$'s in all $p$ entries?

Comment: @ThePointer Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112835/discussion-between-jean-claude-arbaut-and-the-pointer).

Answer (score 1):

In linear regression, the equation linking the features $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_p) \in \mathbb R^p$, coefficients $\beta =(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_p) \in \mathbb R^p$, the intersept $\beta_0 \in \mathbb R$, and output is $\widehat{y} \in \mathbb R$, is
$$
\widehat{y} = \beta^Tx + \beta_0. \tag{1}
$$

- This is clearly equation of a line in the $(p+1)$-dimensional space $\mathbb R^{p+1} = \{(x,y) \mid x \in \mathbb R^p,\; y  \in \mathbb R\}$, which doesn't go through the origin (except if $\beta_0 = 0$).
- **Projectivization.** Now, let $\widetilde{x} := (1,x) = (1,x_1,\ldots,x_p)$ and $\widetilde{\beta} := (\beta_0,\beta) := (\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_p)$. We can rewrite this equation as
  $$\widehat{y} = \beta^Tx + \beta_0 = \sum_{j=1}^p\beta_j x_j + \beta_0\cdot 1 = \sum_{j=1}^{p+1}\widetilde{\beta}^T\widetilde{x},
  $$
  which is clearly the equation of a line through the origin, in the $(p+1)$-dimensional **[real-projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space)** space $\mathbb P\mathbb R^{p+1} := \{(1,x,y) \mid x \in \mathbb R^p,\;y \in \mathbb R\} \cup \infty$, where $\infty := \{(0,x,y) \mid y \ne 0 \lor \exists j,\;x_j \ne 0\}$ is the **point at infinity**.

The apparent difference between the two geometric intepretations (line not going through origin versus line going through origin) boils down to the difference between the real vector-space $\mathbb R^{p+1}$ and its projectivization $\mathbb P\mathbb R^{p+1} := \{(1,z) \mid z \in \mathbb R^{p+1}\} \cup \infty$,where $\infty := \{(0,z) \mid z \in \mathbb R^{p+1} \mid \exists j,\;z_j \ne 0\}$.

Let me know if you need more details on anything I've said...

Comment: The set $\{(1,z)\mid z\in\mathbb R^{p+1}\}$ is not the projective space for two reasons: 1) The elements of the projective space are equivalence classes of non-zero vectors up to non-zero scalar multiples, usually written in homogeneous coordinates like $(1:x_1:\dots:x_p)$. 2) You are missing the projective points with first coordinate equal to zero, i.e. $(0:z_1:\dots:z_p)$ with at least one $z_i\neq 0$!

Comment: @Christoph Good points. Carelessly typed this down from my phone on a train. Indeed, what I defined is projective space with the **point infinity** ripped off. See update.

Comment: How is the line $\widehat{y} = \beta^Tx + \beta_0 = \sum_{j=1}^p\beta_j x_j + \beta_0\cdot 1 = \sum_{j=1}^{p+1}\widetilde{\beta}^T\widetilde{x}$ through the origin, compared to the (other) line in $\mathbb R^{p+1} = \{(x,y) \mid x \in \mathbb R^p,\; y  \in \mathbb R\}$, which isn't? Your introduction of projective geometry seems like it's on the right track; I've studied a bit of projective geometry, and when the authors mentioned $(p + 1)$-dimensions, it immediately reminded me of projective space (although, it really wasn't clear to me how projective geometry was relevant to the context).

Answer (score 0):

The space is described in terms of a projective space, which means that you are dealing with vectors of the form $(X_{0}, X_{1}, \ldots, X_{p}) \in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}$, where two vectors are considered equivalent if they are scalar multiples of each other.

You usually take representative vectors from each equivalence class by requiring that the first nonzero entry is $1$.  You can consider the points with $X_{0}=0$ to be the hyperplane at infinity, so your affine points are those for which $X_{0} \neq 0$ (and can assumed to be $X_{0}=1$). This gives a copy of the affine space $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ as the set of these vectors with $X_{0}=1$, and the "origin" here can be taken as the vector $(1,0,\ldots,0)$.

Okay, now from this, assuming we included the constant $1$ in our input vector, for each $X = (X_{1}, \ldots, X_{p})$ we define $\hat{Y} = (1, X_{1}, \ldots, X_{p})^{T} \hat{\beta} = \hat{Y}$. Then if we look at the vectors $(1, X_{1}, \ldots, X_{p}, \hat{Y})$, these vectors satisfy the equation $(1, X_{1}, \ldots, X_{p}, \hat{Y})^{T}(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}, \ldots, \beta_{p}, -1) = 0$.

Okay, if you know a little projective geometry, the set of vectors $x$ satisfying a homogeneous equation $x^{T} b = 0$ for a fixed vector $b$ form a hyperplane of the projective space; if we require that the first coordinate of $x$ is 1, then we are looking for the intersection of this projective hyperplane with the affine space mentioned above, giving a hyperplane of the affine space (this is different than the hyperplane of a vector space, which must contain the origin). Therefore, the points of the form $(X, \hat{Y})$ give us a hyperplane of this affine space $\mathbb{R}^{p+1}$ (here I am using a hyperplane to mean an affine subspace of codimension 1, different from a vector subspace in that it can be a translation $v+H$ of a vector subspace $H$).

If we do it the way I described above, this hyperplane obtained above does NOT contain the origin, because if we fix $X_{1}=X_{2}=\cdots=X_{p}=0$, then we must have $\hat{Y}=\beta_{0}$, therefore it slices the "y-axis" at $(0,\beta_{0})$. So we find ourselves in the case where we have not "included the constant variable 1 in X". I don't totally understand what he means by this statement, except that he would like to fudge things a little to absorb this extra variable $X_{0}$ somehow so he does not have to worry about fiddly notation. In my reading, he is not explicit about how he includes this, and in fact he makes no mention at all of an $X_{0}$.

In general you will find that textbooks on this topic are not very mathematically clear or rigorous. For example this author doesn't ever define a hyperplane, they only vaguely describe them in Chapter 4 where they mention that they sort of play loosely with the normal definition. So I think you will find madness if you try to take anything more than a big picture idea from a text like this written by a computer scientist.

Comment: Overall I am unable to give a real concrete answer to your exact question, but I hope this helps understand some of the concepts better.

Comment: Thanks. I am working my way through your answer now. I understand what an equivalence class is, but I'm not clear on what this means: "You usually take representative vectors from each equivalence class by requiring that the first nonzero entry is 1."

Comment: @ThePointer Since $(1, x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{p})$, $(2, 2x_{1}, 2x_{2}, \ldots, 2x_{p})$, $(3, 3x_{1}, 3x_{2}, \ldots, 3x_{p})$, etc. all represent the same vector under this equivalence relation, you can take $(1, x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{p})$ as a convenient representative for the equivalence class. You essentially "normalize" your vectors by multiplying them by a nonzero scalar (which gives an equivalent vector) to make the first nonzero coordinate equal 1.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I'm not sure why you were downvoted (wasn't me). I'm now trying to understand this part: "Then if we look at the vectors $(1, X_{1}, \ldots, X_{p}, \hat{Y})$, these vectors satisfy the equation $(1, X_{1}, \ldots, X_{p}, \hat{Y})^{T}(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}, \ldots, \beta_{p}, -1) = 0$." How is this relevant?

Comment: @ThePointer It shows the set of vectors that satisfy this equation (essentially the same equation as $X^{T}\beta = \hat{Y}$) is a hyperplane, since it is the null space of a matrix with just one row.

Comment: I would say, if you want to learn this material from a mathematical point of view, study up on lots of linear algebra (and projective geometry; one good rigorous source for some of this material is Geometric Algebra by E. Artin, you can get a Dover version for cheap). Of course I am a pure mathematician that does not work in machine learning, so I am going to lead you towards a theoretical understanding of the linear algebra  used in studying affine and projective geometry.

Comment: Did you see Jean-Claude Arbaut's answer? It seems that the textbook reasoning is wrong anyway.

Comment: @ThePointer That is a very good answer, and goes with what I am saying that the author is simply being unrigorous for the sake of simplifying some things. It is good that Jean-Claude was able to point out exactly what concepts were being abused. I still highly recommend the source I mentioned above, you will see that it is often not a big deal in the field of machine learning to be imprecise because you are looking at big-picture stuff, but it is good to have a solid understanding of the fundamentals anyway.

Comment: Ok, I have just purchased *Geometric Algebra* by E. Artin. I had also already started studying *Introduction to Projective Geometry* by C. R. Wylie, Jr.